# How i Modify my magento 2 theme in my theme css is integrated but HTML not

Tags: magento2, css, html

I am new and learn Magento 2. I am creating my new custom theme in Magento 2 and integrated my HTML and CSS.HTML is not showing on my page but CSS work How I apply HTML in my theme and modify my theme[image]

this is my theme Structure

Comment: have you tried cache flush and static content deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to flush the cache, these are the 2 most commons ways to do so:

1. In the terminal navigate to the folder where Magento is installed and run `php bin magento cache:flush`

or

2. Login to the admin and navigate to `system > cache management` and click on Flush Magento Cache

Comment: I already clear my cache but my HTML file is not see

Answer (score 0):

In order for your custom HTML to render, you must declare the page reference in XML. So assuming your parent theme is Luma: in your layout/default.xml file you need to declare something similar to:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="-">
</referenceContainer>
```

Further reading: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html